# JS + Socket.io + Heroku Problems - Socket.id problem

Tags: javascript, heroku, socket.io

---

### Solution

Change

```
var server = app.listen(3000);
```

To

```
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

---

I want to deploy an game made with JavaScript on Heroku.

Here's my server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);
var socket = require('socket.io');
var io = socket(server);
app.use(express.static('public'));

var connectedPlayers = {};

console.log("Server is running!");

io.on('connection',

function (socket) {

    socket.on('newPlayer',
        function (data) {
            console.log("New player connected - ID: " + data.id);
            connectedPlayers[socket.id] = {
                idOnline: socket.id,
                idOffline: data.id,
                x: data.w,
                y: data.h
            };
            socket.emit('allPlayers', connectedPlayers);
            socket.broadcast.emit('newPlayer', connectedPlayers[socket.id]);
        });

    socket.on('move',
        function (data) {
            connectedPlayers[socket.id].x = data.x;
            connectedPlayers[socket.id].y = data.y;
            socket.broadcast.emit('move', connectedPlayers[socket.id]);
        });

    socket.on('message',
        function (data) {
            message = {
                name: data.name,
                message: data.message,
                messageId: generateId()
            };
            socket.broadcast.emit('message', message);
        });

    socket.on('emote',
        function (data) {
            message = {
                emote: data.emote,
                id: socket.id
            }
            socket.broadcast.emit('emote', message);
        });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        delete connectedPlayers[socket.id];
        io.emit('remove', socket.id);
    });

});
```

This work's fine locally, but when I deploy to heroku I get this error message:

```
2018-11-23T21:04:18.009491+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/server.js:33
2018-11-23T21:04:18.009512+00:00 app[web.1]: connectedPlayers[socket.id].x = data.x;
2018-11-23T21:04:18.009514+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-11-23T21:04:18.009516+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-11-23T21:04:18.009518+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot set property 'x' of undefined
```

I understand that heroku is not recognizing the "connectedPlayers" array at that index, but how this can work properly locally?
What's wrong with the socket.id property?
PS.: the socket.id it's sended by the client, but I think that's generated after a client establish an connection with the server right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for a lot of solutions, I was trying crazy things to insert the:

```
process.env.PORT || 5000
```

on the server.listen.

As you can see in the code of the question, I've posted an out of date code, with the following line (my first try):

```
var server = app.listen(3000);
```

The solution was simplier than I thought, just changing the above line of code to:

```
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```